# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException when saving multiple tables at once

Tags: jquery, ajax, entity-framework, web-services

I want to insert to all these tables at one go, everything goes well in the debugger until it hits SaveChanges() method and I get the "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" error!

Tables:

```
  public partial class EmployementRequest
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public EmployementRequest()
    {
        this.EmployeeCourses = new Collection<EmployeeCours>();
        this.EmployeeLanguages = new Collection<EmployeeLanguage>();
        this.EmployeeSkills = new Collection<EmployeeSkill>();
    }

    public System.Guid PKEmploymentRequest { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FKPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surnam { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string IDCardNumber { get; set; }
    public string IDCity { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Birthplace { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Religion { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cell { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyName { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyPhone { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyAddress { get; set; }
    public string ParentedPeople { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MarriageStatus { get; set; }
    public string Residency { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceStatus { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceCode { get; set; }
    public string VehicleStatus { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public string MilitaryServiceStatus { get; set; }
    public string EducationGrade { get; set; }
    public string EducatedFrom { get; set; }
    public string EducationField { get; set; }
    public string Illness { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> ExtraWorkCapability { get; set; }
    public string LeisureTimeHobbies { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public string IntroductionMethod { get; set; }
    public string IntroducerName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual Collection<EmployeeCours> EmployeeCourses { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual Collection<EmployeeLanguage> EmployeeLanguages { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual Collection<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
}


    public partial class EmployeeCours
{
    public System.Guid PKEmlpoyeeCourse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FKEmployementRequest { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Association { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployementRequest EmployementRequest { get; set; }
}

 public partial class EmployeeLanguage
{
    public System.Guid PKEmployeeLanguage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FKEmploymentRequest { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ComprehensionLevel { get; set; }
    public string WritingLevel { get; set; }
    public string ConversationLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployementRequest EmployementRequest { get; set; }
}
   public partial class EmployeeSkill
{
    public System.Guid PKEmployeeSkill { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FKEmploymentRequest { get; set; }
    public string Skill { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployementRequest EmployementRequest { get; set; }
}
```

JQuery AJAX function to retrieve inserted data from form:

```
  function addEmployementRequest() {
        var emp = {};
        var el = {};
        var es = {};
        var ec = {};
        emp.name = $("#inputName").val();
        emp.surnam = $('#inputSurname').val();
        emp.father = $('#inputFather').val();
        emp.idNumber = $('#inputIDNumber').val();
        emp.idCardNumber = $('#inputIDCardNumber').val();
        emp.idCity = $('#inputIDCity').val();
        emp.birthday = $('#inputBirthday').val();
        emp.birthplace = $('#inputBirthplace').val();
        emp.Nationality = $('#inputNationality').val();
        emp.Religion = $('#inputReligion').val();
        emp.Phone = $('#inputPhone').val();
        emp.Cell = $('#inputCell').val();
        emp.Address = $('#inputAddress').val();
        emp.emergencyName = $('#inputEmergencyName').val();
        emp.emergencyPhone = $('#inputEmergencyPhone').val();
        emp.emergencyAddress = $('#inputEmergencyAddress').val();
        emp.parentedPeople = $('#inputParentedPeople').val();
        emp.gender = $("input[name='radioGender']:checked").val();
        emp.marriageStatus = $('#inputParentedPeople').val();
        emp.Residency = $('#selectResidenceStatus option:selected').val();
        emp.insuranceStatus = $('#radioInsurance:checked').val();
        emp.insuranceCode = $('#inputInsuranceCode').val();
        emp.vehicleType = $('#selectVehicleType option:selected').text();
        emp.educationGrade = $('#selectEducationGrade option:selected').text();
        emp.educatedFrom = $('#inputEducatedFrom').val();
        emp.educationField = $('#inputEducationField').val();
        emp.illness = $('#inputllness').val();
        emp.ExtraWorkCapability = $('#checkboxExtraWorkCapability').is(':checked');
        emp.leisureTimeHobbies = $('#inputLeisureTimeHobbies').val();
        emp.salary = $('#inputSalary').val();
        emp.introductionMethod = $('#inputIntroductionMethod').val();
        emp.introducerName = $('#inputIntroducerName').val();
        var today = new Date();
        emp.createdOn = today.toLocaleDateString("Eng-US");
        emp.startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        emp.endDate = $('#endDate').val();
        emp.position = $('#position').val();
        emp.prevSalary = $('#prevsalary').val();
        emp.separationReason = $('#separationReason').val();

        el.Name = $('#langName').val(),
            el.ComprehensionLevel = $('#comprehensionLevel').val(),
            el.WritingLevel = $('#writingLevel').val(),
            el.ConversationLevel = $('#conversationLevel').val();
        ec.Date = $('#courseDate').val(),
            ec.Course = $('#course').val(),
            ec.Duration = $('#duration').val(),
            ec.Association = $('#association').val(),
            ec.Description = $('#courseDescription').val();
        es.Skill = $('#skill').val(),
            es.skillDescription = $('#skillDescription').val();
        //emp.EmployeeCourses = [
        //{
        //    Course: $('#course').val(),
        //    Description: $('#courseDescription'),
        //    Duration: $('#duration').val(),
        //    Date: $('#courseDate').val(),
        //    Association: $('#association').val
        //}
        //];
        //emp.EmployeeSkills = [
        //{
        //    skill: $('#skill').val(),
        //    skillDescription:$('#skillDescription').val()
        //}];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'EmployementRequestPage.asmx/AddEmployementRequest',
            method: 'post',
            data: '{emp:' + JSON.stringify(emp) + ',el:' + JSON.stringify(el) + ',es:' + JSON.stringify(es) + ',ec:' + JSON.stringify(ec) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });

    };
```

Mehod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddEmployementRequest(EmployementRequest emp,EmployeeLanguage el,EmployeeSkill es,EmployeeCours ec)
    {
        emp.PKEmploymentRequest = Guid.NewGuid();

        EmployeeSkill employeeSkill = new EmployeeSkill
        {
            PKEmployeeSkill = new Guid(),
            FKEmploymentRequest = emp.PKEmploymentRequest,
            Skill = es.Skill,
            Description = es.Description
        };
        EmployeeLanguage employeeLanguage = new EmployeeLanguage
        {
            FKEmploymentRequest = emp.PKEmploymentRequest,
            PKEmployeeLanguage = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ComprehensionLevel = el.ComprehensionLevel,
            ConversationLevel = el.ConversationLevel,
            WritingLevel = el.WritingLevel,
            Name = el.Name
        };
        EmployeeCours employeeCours = new EmployeeCours
        {
            PKEmlpoyeeCourse = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FKEmployementRequest = emp.PKEmploymentRequest,
            Date = ec.Date ,
            Course = ec.Course,
            Duration = ec.Duration,
            Association = ec.Association,
            Description = ec.Description
        };
        EmployementRequest employementRequest = new EmployementRequest
        {
            Name = emp.Name,
            Address = emp.Address,
            Surnam = emp.Surnam,
            Father = emp.Father,
            IDNumber = emp.IDNumber,
            IDCardNumber = emp.IDNumber,
            IDCity = emp.IDCity,
            Birthday = emp.Birthday,
            Birthplace = emp.Birthplace,
            Nationality = emp.Nationality,
            Religion = emp.Religion,
            Phone = emp.Phone,
            Cell = emp.Cell,
            EmergencyAddress = emp.EmergencyAddress,
            EmergencyName = emp.EmergencyName,
            EmergencyPhone = emp.EmergencyPhone,
            ParentedPeople = emp.ParentedPeople,
            Gender = emp.Gender,
            MarriageStatus = emp.MarriageStatus,
            Residency = emp.Residency,
            InsuranceCode = emp.InsuranceCode,
            InsuranceStatus = emp.InsuranceStatus,
            VehicleType = emp.VehicleType,
            MilitaryServiceStatus = emp.MilitaryServiceStatus,
            EducatedFrom = emp.EducatedFrom,
            EducationField = emp.EducationField,
            EducationGrade = emp.EducationGrade,
            ExtraWorkCapability = emp.ExtraWorkCapability,
            LeisureTimeHobbies = emp.LeisureTimeHobbies,
            Salary = emp.Salary,
            IntroducerName = emp.IntroducerName,
            IntroductionMethod = emp.IntroductionMethod,
            Illness = emp.Illness,
            VehicleStatus = emp.VehicleStatus,
        };
        employementRequest.EmployeeLanguages.Add(employeeLanguage);
        employementRequest.EmployeeSkills.Add(employeeSkill);
        employementRequest.EmployeeCourses.Add(employeeCours);
        using (var db = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities())
        {

            db.EmployementRequests.Add(employementRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enclose your code on a try catch with Update Exception or DbValidationException `ex`:

```
try 
{
    using (var db = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities())
        {

            db.EmployementRequests.Add(employementRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
     //get exception and debug
}
catch(UpdateException ex)
{
     //get exception and debug
}
```

Comment: I realized what the actual error is.Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint